# Concordance <java> (drjava)

Tags: java, string

So I am currently working on an older program for practice and the directions say "You can create a class that represents the collection of these WordRecords, this should have an ArrayList(or Vector) of WordRecords and various methods to help in accessing the Records. For example a method called addWord(String word, String prefix, int lineNum ) would be useful. It would first check to see if the word is already in the collection: if it is then just add the prefixed line number to the WordRecord in the  collection, if it isn’t then create a new WordRecord for this word." So I'm all good with the WordRecord class and am currently working on the WordCollection class and I'm stuck on the addword method. Here's what I have (just a skeleton).

```
public void addWord( String word, String prefix, String linenum )
{

}
```

Comment: This is a fairly simple process of adding entries to a Map.  If you want to make it interesting make it a KWIC index instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public void addWord( String word, String prefix, String linenum )
{   //if word exists, just add the prefix
    //theCollection = your ArrayList of WordRecord
    boolean findIt = false;
    for(WordRecord wordRecord : theCollection){
        if(wordRecord.getWord().equals(word)){
           wordRecord.addPrefix(prefix); //this method should be add a prefix
           findIt = true; 
           break;
        }
    }
    if(!findIt){
     WordRecord newRecord = new WordRecord();
     newRecord.setWord(word);
     newRecord.addPrefix(prefix);
     newRecord.setLineNum(linenum);
     //... and add
     theCollection.add(newRecord);
    }
 }
```

Comment: For each entry in theCollection (except ones that actually match) that adds a new entry.  And you're mutating theCollection while iterating on it, leading to some possible problems.  The method *should* do a simple search for the word in a Map, then add it to the Map if not found.  With no loop.

Comment: Thank you! Don't know why I couldn't figure that out.